# Add to cart logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a logic for add to cart, where user can add items to cart and when item is already in the cart, it's quantity is increased, but something in the code is not right and I can't tell what. The problem is that the for loop where it's said to check ids of all the items in the list and if one exists, increase it's quantity, but it looks like it works only for the first item that is added, and the rest are just being pushed to the session storage. Hope you can help. Here is the code:

```
const addToCart = (data) => {
    let items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cartItems);

    if (items.length === 0) {
        data.qty = 1;
        items.push(data);
        sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(items));
        console.log("first");
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i]._id === data._id) {
                items[i].qty++;
                sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(items));
                console.log("second");
                break;
            } else if (items[i]._id !== data._id) {
                data.qty = 1;
                items.push(data);
                sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(items));
                console.log("third");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the case `length === 0`:

```js
let found = false;
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i]._id === data._id) {
        items[i].qty++;
        found=true;
        break;
     } 
}

if (found === false) {
    data.qty = 1;
    items.push(data);
}

sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(items));
```

And yes, the problem in your code is the `else if`: You are adding the data item for each item in the array where the id is not the one of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way without for loop:

```
  const addToCart = (data) => {
    // initialize items to empty array if empty
    let items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cartItems) || [];

    if (items.some((item) => item._id === data._id)) {
      // item is already in cart, increase qty for that item
      items = items.map((item) =>
        item._id === data._id ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : item
      );
    } else {
      // new item, add to cart
      items = [...items, { ...data, qty: 1 }];
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(items));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the logic is that, you are breaking the "for" loop in the "else if" condition. So, your logic will only work if the first item matches with the "_id" in "data".

Solution :
Remove the "break" statement from the "else if" condition of your "for" loop.

Comment: It still duplicates items in the list. When add a new item to the cart it console.logs:  "first". Then every thing else is third -> second. It just multiplies.

Comment: Yes, there is no need of the "else if" statement in this logic. @Taxel has already answered,

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems a bit complex for solving this issue, your problem is, you effectively only compare the `data._id` with `items[0]._id` and push a new item if the ids doesn't match and break, so you never end up checking the id of any other element and just push a new one

The answer of *[Taxel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68496531/14764125)* will solve your issue

---

Here is another simple logic to also solve your problem, without using a for loop

```js
const addToCart = (data) => {
  let items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cartItems);
    
  let itemIndex = items.findIndex(e => e._id === data._id);
    
  if(itemIndex > -1) {
    // item exists
    items[itemIndex].qty++;
  }
  else {
    // item not found
    data.qty = 1;
    items.push(data);
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(items));
}
```